# using debug information in shared object files

Tags: linux, debugging, binary

I'm searching a bug, which crashes my application only on our build server but not on my machine. So the only information I get is an error file containing the stack with methods and binary offsets within those methods (in the compiled machine code) where the SIGSEGV occoured, i.e.,

```
V  [libjvm.so+0x2816c5]  EventsRuntime::fire_gc_start_end(signed char, signed char, GCCause::Cause, bool)+0x125
V  [libjvm.so+0x27b72d]  EventsGCRuntime::fire_gc_start(signed char, GCCause::Cause)+0x7d
V  [libjvm.so+0x91ea35]  G1CollectedHeap::do_collection(bool, bool, unsigned long)+0x1195
V  [libjvm.so+0x1200534]  VM_G1CollectFull::doit()+0xa4
V  [libjvm.so+0x11fed83]  VM_Operation::evaluate()+0xb3
V  [libjvm.so+0x11fc1d8]  VMThread::evaluate_operation(VM_Operation*)+0x448
V  [libjvm.so+0x11fca33]  VMThread::loop()+0x263
V  [libjvm.so+0x11fd000]  VMThread::run()+0xe0
V  [libjvm.so+0xef2662]  java_start(Thread*)+0xf2
```

When I'm executing on my machine, I can debug the source code in netbeans, so my conclusion is that there is proper debug information, associating the machine code with the source code. However, my question now is, how can i translate these binary offsets to an actual source code line? Is there any tool I can do this with?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Build with debug information and optimizations (e.g. `-O2 -g3`).

Comment: I already do, the error dump file does not contain more information. So i need to extract it somehow.

Comment: If you are building libjvm yourself and not getting the debug information, then you are not building it right. If you are using a prebuilt third-party libjvm, you are not going to get the debug information because it's not there.